# How to tell if PNG file has an Alpha Channel / Transparency

Tags: objective-c, macos, png, alpha, alpha-transparency

Trying to find the best / easiest way using Objective C on MAC OSX if a PNG file has an Alpha Channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/image/test.png"];
BOOL alpha = [rep hasAlpha];
```

Comment: Very nicely done.  I am an iOS guy and I looked for something like this but could not find.  Thanks Again....

Answer (score 0):

If the color-type byte, which is at a known location within the IHDR chunk, is 0, 2, or 3 AND there is no tRNS chunk present before the first IDAT chunk, there is no alpha channel and the image is opaque.  If a tRNS chunk is present, or if the color-type is 4 or 6, the image has an alpha channel, which might have transparency in some pixels or it might be opaque.

Comment: Thanks, was researching this. Was wondering if there was an API like in iOS with CGImage that has an api for YES or NO.